# Why does this vim autocommand to jump to the last known cursor position in a file work on OS X but not my Ubuntu VM?

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I've got the following in my `.vimrc` (from [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#last-position-jump)):

```
autocmd BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

This works perfectly on my local machine, but on my Ubuntu VM (VirtualBox) it doesn't. Any ideas why?

**Edit**

Here's the output of `vim --version` if it helps:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:25:35)
Included patches: 1-429
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
+mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: Is it exactly the same `.vimrc` on your VM ?

Comment: Yup, exactly. I even copied and pasted it in again from here to make sure.

Comment: And the vim versions? Especialy the patch level?

Comment: Is anything else from the .vimrc taken (settings, mappings, etc.)? Does `'"` jump when typed manually?

Comment: When I hit `'"` it jumps to the top of the file, but I don't have that mapped to anything in [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/ysim/dotfiles/blob/master/common/vimrc) :|

Comment: There was an `s` at the end of "versions".